# Package scanning Spring 3 context:component-scan

Tags: spring-3

in the `<context:component-scan base-package=`
is there any diference in doing `com.mycompany.proyect.dao` or `com.mycompany`. I have this doubt because in both ways works. I have a project **A** that access some data, this project is packed as a jar, then the project **B** imports project **A**. Both have different package structure like `com.mycompany.proyectA.dao` and `com.mycompany.proyectB.dao`. So, to make the component scanning work. i declared the `context:component-scan` as follows `com.mycompany`. I must to say that this declaration is working, but in every example in spring (or other places) always use `com.mycompany.dao`. Are there some issues working in this way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there seems to some conflict between DAO methods in `com.mycompany.proyectA.dao` and `com.mycompany.proyectB.dao`

The solution is to split into 2 context:component-scan one for projectADao and one for projectBDao.

Further more you can split the context:component-scan in 2 xml files like `daoA.xml and daoB.xml` and then have a context:component-scan in each , `ex: context:component-scan as com.mycompany.proyectA.dao` and  `context:component-scan as com.mycompany.proyectB.dao` respectively.

Comment: It sounds good and i think it might work, but my question is about the issues declaring com.mycompany.dao or just declaring com.mycompany. Thank you.